# How to draw an edge between two node in cytoscape with mouse drag drop

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using cutoscape.js library for visualizing graphs in web.
i want to add some node and edges between them. adding node is simple.
i want to draw an edge between source node and destination node with drag and drop.
If you can help me, i will appreciate you .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please [do your research first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), this can be solved by simply going over to the [docs](https://js.cytoscape.org) and browsing throug the [extensions](https://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/ui-extensions):

- The solution is using [Edge-Handles](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles)

```
let cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('#cy'),
    /* ... */
});

let defaults = { /* ... */ };

let eh = cy.edgehandles( defaults );
```

If you need an example, take a look at [this](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles/blob/master/demo.html).